# Phrases or idioms which mean "I did not do my homework"

Tags: meaning

İs there any idom or phrase to say you did not prepare your homework?

For example, my teacher gives me homework. Let's assume that I did not do my homework, what should I say?

Comment: You should say the truth. It's much better than an idiom expressing a falsehood. :)

Comment: Are you thinking of an idiom in your native language? If you give that, it might help see what you're really asking.

Comment: If you are Down Under: "My dingo ate my homework."

Comment: Yeah, "My dog ate my homework" is common in the US.

Comment: Say, "Sorry, I didn't do my homework."

Answer (score 1):

*The dog ate my homework* is probably the idiomatic expression more commonly associated with an excuse for not doing your homework:

> ***“[The dog ate my homework](https://www.dictionary.com/e/dog-ate-my-homework-origin/)”***  is used as a stock example of the kind of silly excuses schoolchildren give for why their work isn’t finished.
>
> According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the first example of the dog ate my homework excuse in print can be found in a speech given by retiring headmaster James Bewsher in 1929 and published in the Manchester Guardian: “It is a long time since I have had the excuse about the dog tearing up the arithmetic homework.” The way this comment is phrased suggests that the whole dog ate my homework story had been around for some time before it was put in print.

(Dictionary.com)